# Using Escape characters in openCSV

Tags: java, csv

I am using the default constructor and the default escape character which is backslash.
So the CSV format is like this `"value1","value2","value3","value4"`

The values are read from the CSV file , Windows XP OS.

Now the problem is that when the value as a double quote in it like this `"aa"," I am "fine", what about u?", "232",` I do not understand how to escape the double quote.

Can some one please help me here?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. Do you input/read string from the console or just assigning string literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quote the quote characters

```
    CSVParser csv = new CSVParser()

    String[] result = csv.parseLine('"aa","I am ""fine"", what about u?", "232"')

    assert result[0] == 'aa'
    assert result[1] == 'I am "fine", what about u?'
    assert result[2] == '232'
```

## Update

This answer was an extract from the following [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) test file **OpenCSVTest.groovy**:

```
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='net.sf.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='2.3')
])

class OpenCSVTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testParseQuote() {
        CSVParser csv = new CSVParser()

        String[] result = csv.parseLine('"aa","I am ""fine"", what about u?", "232"')

        assert result[0] == 'aa'
        assert result[1] == 'I am "fine", what about u?'
        assert result[2] == '232'
    }
}
```

Run as follows:

```
$ groovy OpenCSVTest
.
Time: 0.009

OK (1 test)
```

Comment: @user714965 I use groovy to test my Java code. It's easy to convert to Java, just add semi-colons :-)

Comment: Double quoting the double quote characters works fine. Thanks @Mark O'Connor .

Answer (score 0):

In your question you tell that you are using the default escape character which is backslash. So you have to use the backslash... Like: `"aa"," I am \"fine\", what about u?", "232"`

Test it from code like this:

```
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser();
String[] parseLine = csvParser.parseLine("\"aa\",\" I am \"\"fine\"\", what about u?\", \"232\"");
```

Comment: Those slashes are escaping the quote character when Java assembles the string. They're not being passed to the CSVParser object.

Comment: This does not work, already tried it. Thanks anyway @user714965.